# Problema ao passar informações para outra tela

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Olá, tenho o seguinte problema. Preciso passar informações pra uma outra tela porém não recebo nada no controlador na minha segunda tela. Mais detalhes:

[Tela principal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdfNa.png)
Quando clico no editar eu pego o titulo e a descrição no documentSnapshot e coloco no titleController, descController e chamo essa nova tela  através desse código

```
Future<void> _createOrUpdate([DocumentSnapshot? documentSnapshot]) async {
    if (documentSnapshot != null) {
      titleController.text = documentSnapshot['title'].toString();
      descController.text = documentSnapshot['desc'].toString();
      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TelaSelecaoDeImagem()));
    }
  }
```

[Minha segunda tela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY5If.png) O que eu quero fazer é exibir o title e o Desc nessa tela. Porém não sei exatamente o que fazer.

O que eu tentei e não deu certo foi instanciar um objeto da primeira tela e tentar exibir na segunda tela. Através do seguinte código:

Instanciando o objeto da classe da minha primeira tela:

```
HomePageState fieldController = HomePageState();
```

Tentando mostrar pra ver se eu conseguia algo:

```
print(fieldController.titleController.text);
```

Resultado:
[Resultado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gITdM.png)

Pedi ajuda pra alguns grupos e a maioria disse que a solução é usar um tal de **GetX**, porém eu não sei nem o Flutter direito, acredito que vou ter dificuldade porém se esse for o caso terei que aprender. Alguem pode me ajudar, desde já agradeço a disposição. E se precisarem de qualquer detalhe adicional estou a disposição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua tentativa não deu certo pois a instância da primeira tela criada na segunda é uma nova, cujos campos ainda não foram populados. É uma instância diferente da instância que tem o título e a descrição preenchidos. Se você conseguisse uma referência a instância correta, sua tentativa funcionaria (embora de uma maneira relativamente deselegante).

Nesse caso, o jeito *mais fácil* de resolver seu problema é criar propriedades na segunda tela para acessar diretamente de lá. Para preencher essas propriedades, você pode criar um construtor que recebe elas por parâmetro:

- Crie os campos que você precisa na segunda tela:

```
String title;
String desc;
```

- Crie um construtor para a segunda tela que receba esses argumentos e armazene eles. O mais simples modo de fazer isso é:

```
TelaSelecaoDeImagem({Key? key, this.title, this.desc})
      : super(key: key);
```

Com isso, sua segunda tela já vai ter os campos que você precisa. Se ela for um *StatefulWidget*, e você precisar acessar esses campos de dentro da sua respectiva classe de estado, você pode usar a propriedade `widget`. Por exemplo:

```
print(widget.title);
```

- Por último, lembre-se de popular esses campos ao criar a segunda tela. Isso ocorre quando você faz o *push*:

```
Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TelaSelecaoDeImagem(title: titleController.text, desc: descController.text)))
```

(Com o texto que achar válido.)

O exemplo completo, aplicado em seu caso, segue abaixo:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TelaSelecaoDeImagem extends StatefulWidget{
  TelaSelecaoDeImagem({Key? key, this.title, this.desc})
      : super(key: key); // O construtor que permite receber seus dois parâmetros.

  String title;
  String desc; // Onde as propriedades com seus textos devem ficar.

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new TelaSelecaoDeImagemState();
  }
}

class TelaSelecaoDeImagemState extends State<TelaSelecaoDeImagem>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
        widget.title // Se quiser acessar aqui, lembre-se de usar a propriedade widget.
    )
  }
}
```

O nome disso é *gerenciamento de estado* e é um tópico bem extenso e para horas de discussão. Estado é o nome que se dá a essas variáveis que você usa para construir sua tela, como criamos ali.

No seu caso, era uma tela simples que só precisava receber dois textos. Porém conforme o aplicativo cresce, esse tipo de abordagem acaba não sendo tão simples. Fazer isso em uma escala grande é impraticável.

Podem ter múltiplos widgets que precisam de múltiplas variáveis de estado com ações que alterem o estado de outros widgets na árvore. Nesses casos, é recomendado utilizar um gerenciamento de estados mais elaborado, e diversas alternativas podem ser encontradas na [documentação oficial da Google](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) (em inglês). Nessa mesma página tem também um [link](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro) para uma introdução ao assunto, com um exemplo que pode ser interessante olhar depois.

Getx é um pacote que tem esse como um dos objetivos (e foi feito por brasileiros). Mas ele é só uma opção dentre muitas. No site que coloquei acima outras são listadas que talvez sejam mais simples e diretas de entender. Caso decida estudar esse assunto no futuro, recomendo escolher a que melhor se encaixe com os seus objetivos.

Comment: Ah @Naslausky o que seria de mim sem você, perfeita explicação. Consegui resolver meu problema graças a você novamente. Agradeço demais, muito obrigado.